# How to use update cursor dynamicaly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to encode my data by this rule:  according to the length of current word I change the letters of the word and update it in the same table, I'm not sure how to use the UPDATE cursor in that case, would love to get examples.
This is my current code:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(30)       
DECLARE currentCursor  CURSOR for select Lastname from contact;
OPEN  currentCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM currentCursor INTO @name                    
            Declare @Length int =0;     
            Declare @newName varchar(30)
            select @Length =   LEN(@name);  
             --     DECLARE currentCursor2  CURSOR for update
            while @Length >0
                begin
                    set @newName = concat( @newName,  CHAR(CAST(27 * RAND() + 224 AS INT)) )
                    set @Length = @Length -1;                                                           
               end
            --  FETCH NEXT FROM currentCursor2 INTO @newName  
                update contact 
                set LastName = @newName
                where lastname = @name
CLOSE currentCursor;
DEALLOCATE currentCursor
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I get a change now but I get the same change in all rows as the first one.. it doesn't move to the next row, so I think maybe to change the update to a cursor update but it doesn't work with a dynamic value so I need an example if possible to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are having are not related to the type of cursor you are using, the main problem is that you are using the cursor syntax incorrectly. You would have the same issue even if you were using an update cursor.

Official documentation of cursors can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

The first issue is because you are only doing one fetch, you need to continually fetch until you get to the end of your result set.

The second issue is that you are not resetting new name between iterations

An updated version of your SQL is below

```
DECLARE @name varchar(30)       
DECLARE currentCursor  CURSOR for select Lastname from contact;
OPEN  currentCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM currentCursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- While the last fetch was successful
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Length int = 0;     
    DECLARE @newName varchar(30) = '' -- reset new name
    SELECT @Length = LEN(@name);  

    WHILE @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @newName = concat( @newName,  CHAR(CAST(27 * RAND() + 224 AS INT)) )
        SET @Length = @Length -1;                                                           
    END

    UPDATE contact 
    SET    LastName = @newName
    WHERE  lastname = @name

    -- Fetch the next row
    FETCH NEXT FROM currentCursor INTO @name   
END
CLOSE currentCursor;
DEALLOCATE currentCursor
```